# Which is better using custom exceptions or using ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling, customization

For both developers and users ??? which one is better ? defining a new custom error like this :

```py
def Passed_Empty_Text(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Empty String Passed'
raise Passed_Empty String
# And More Exceptions
```

or using :

```py
 raise ValueError('Passed Empty String')
```

which one is better ??

Comment: But it could be easily done with ValueError('Not Enough values needed 4')

Comment: if only use ValueError catching error for other programmers using this is easier

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: The answer is "it depends", no-one can answer this without more context and sometimes it is subjective

Comment: i will add more details

Comment: added more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both :)

Inherit from `ValueError` and give your exception a meaningful name.

```
class EmptyError(ValueError):
    ...
```

Now you have a more specific `ValueError` when you need it. Whether this actually increases the user/developer-friendliness depends on personal taste and the larger context.

Comment: can this be catched with try :

Comment: except ValueError:

Comment: @Zer0 yes, any instance of `NotEnoughFoos` *is-a* `ValueError`.

Comment: oh i got it thanks @timegeb

Comment: it doesnt let me accept your answer . needs five minutes

Comment: is it any other way for it ???? this one is great . but maybe there is a better ?? who knows ?